Finding change of basis matrix for bilinear form
I'm having a hard time finding change of basis matrix for bilinear form.
I'm given a matrix $A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 &-1\\
1 & -1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$
and I need to find matrices $D$ and $C$ such that $D = C^TAC$
I've managed to find $D =  
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$ using symmetric Gaussian elimination, but I don't have much clue how to move on from here. Any hint/help would be appreciated!

I'm guessing $A$ is the metric in some basis and you want to change basis with $C$? Do you have the old and new bases by chance?

it is just expressing each symmetric row/column step as an elementary matrix, take the identity and alter just one off-diagonal position.  Call it $C_j$   at step $j,$  this being the matrix that goes on the right in $A_{j}   =   C_j^T  A_{j-1}  C_j.$  Then $C = C_1 C_2 C_3..$  See my http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr

well, why not.  Usually the $C_j$   are upper triangular.  However, if an intermediate step creates a zero on the diagonal, the next step is lower triangular;  $C_1$  (1,2) set to: $-1$   then      $C_2$  (1,3) set to: $-1$   then   $C_3$  (3,2) set to: $1$   then   $C_4$  (2,3) set to: $-1/2 ; ; ; ; $   so this time $C_3$  is lower triangular   Oh...   I got to diagonal $(1,-4,1)$  rather than your $(1,-1,1).$   That can be corrected to your target  with $C_5$    which is diagonal, middle element $1/2$

There is a canonical unitary matrix to diagonalise a bilinear form, which I so called the completing the square tricks. The algorithm is stated below and let $\mathfrak{B}$ be a bilinear form.

Step $1$: Separate all monomials from $x_1$. You can write the bilinear form in $f(x_1,\cdots,x_n)^2+f_2(x_2,\cdots,x_n),f,g$ are monomials.
Step $2$: Apply step $1$ on $f_2$, but this time, we separate all monomials from $x_2$.
Step $3$: We keep applying step $1$ on $f_i$ to separate all monomials from $x_i$ to obtain $f_{i+1}$ until it only contains two variable.

Remark. Sometimes you may not be able to completing the square, like you may get a variable in the form $x_1x_2$ and nothing else. However, we can still write $x_1x_2=\dfrac{1}{4}(x_1+x_2)^2-\dfrac{1}{4}(x_1-x_2)^2.$
Last but not least, you would obtain $\mathfrak{B}$ as a sum of square of monomials. This gives the unitary matrix we want by setting the coefficient of $x_i$ of $f_j$ as the $(i,j)$-th entries, and the whole coefficient of the $f_j$ as the diagonal entries.
Example. We use your example $\mathfrak{B}(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2+2xy-2yz+2xz$.
Step $1$: We have $\mathfrak{B}=(x+y+z)^2-4yz$. So $f=(x+y+z)$ and $f_2=-4yz$.
Step $2$: $-4yz=(y-z)^2-(y+z)^2$.
So $\mathfrak{B}=(x+y+z)^2+(y-z)^2-(y+z)^2$. This gives
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 1\\1 & 1 &-1\\1&-1&1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\1&1&1\\
1&-1&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\
0&-1&0\\
0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\
1&1&1\\
1&-1&1\end{pmatrix}^T$$

Arh yes, this gives diagonalization of bilinear form, but you should taking back the transpose bc you want a form $D=C^TAC$.
